# Why uwp apps take long time to start?

Tags: wpf, winforms, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

Even an uwp app containing nothing but a button starts up slower than a wpf or winform app. Is there any reason behind it?? Is this because of uwp apps running in container that makes the start up process slow??

Comment: Do you mean that it takes long to start it during development in Visual Studio or when it's deployed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emmm, it's the disadvantage of uwp, maybe ms team want to show how fast their code works. But we can do something to make it launch very fast in release mode.

First open `Package.appxmanifest` in text mode.
Insert uap5 at the top of the file.

```
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5"
  ...>
```

Then you need to find label `SplashScreen`.

```
<uap:SplashScreen ... uap5:Optional="true"/>
```

Finally, change to release mode, you will find your app is launching very quickly.